# Beginning Form submit Sharepoint Question

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a basic install of Sharepoint running, and the first programming type task I want to do is make a form to collect some data.
I want to have a page have a form, collect a name and a phone number, submit the form, then have a confirmation page display the saved data.
My basic questions are: do I make my own db, as in a classic web app (if not, do I care where the data is stored?), is the programming similar (I know how to do this in java web apps), and is InfoPath something I should look into to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint is nothing like anything. ;)

Windows Sharepoint Services is a .net application and set of APIs combined with a DB schema that isn't meant to be human readable.

To collect data and store it in SharePoint, there tends to be two typical options:

1) Create a list of some sort (survey, task list, etc.) within the SharePoint GUI, set up permissions, and send it out to have people fill it in.

2) Use InfoPath as the tool to create the form's interface, mapping to a SharePoint list.

These methods can be fairly simple compared to a custom web app, but there are also limitations that may lead you down the path of skipping SharePoint and creating your own web application to collect the data.

Comment: Say I make a database that is external to Sharepoint. There is no way to program Sharepoint to collect data and send it to that db, and later read from that db and display data?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way, but it would beg the question: Why? At that point, I'd say skip SharePoint. FYI, InfoPath can send data to separate DB than SharePoint.

Comment: they why is that I'd like to stick with one website/platform, and do all i need to from it, instead of worrying about maintaining two different applications.

Comment: Just keep in mind that SharePoint is its own thing. Unless you have plans to focus on being a SharePoint developer, it might be easier to maintain your own app alongside SharePoint rather than having to bend to 'The SharePoint Way'. However, based on your intitial scenario, it sounds like you need a rather simple form and rather flat data structure, so just using the standard web UI of SharePoint might get you to what you  need by creating a custom list and applying some workflow rules to it.